# Sum of Denominator where Numerator is not null - Filter issues in PBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

| call_count | tHandle | tTalk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 |  | 2040.01 |
| 7 | 1136.12 | 768.83 |
| 1 | 186.709 |  |

In DAX I want to find the `average` `tHandle` when there of the calls where `tHandle` `is not null`..

I want to be able to sum the `tHandle` where `tHandle` `is not blank` and divide by the `sum` of `call_count` where `tHandle` `is not blank`..

My current DAX is returning `73.49` instead of `165.35` which is `1322.83/8`.

Current DAX:

```
Average Call Handle = sum(vw_fact_conversation_aggregate[tHandle]) /  if(sum(vw_fact_conversation_aggregate[tHandle]) <> BLANK(), sum(vw_fact_conversation_aggregate[call_count]), 0) + 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example:

```
AVGtHandle = 
var _handle = CALCULATE( sum(calls[tHandle]))
var _CallCount = CALCULATE( sum(calls[CallCount]), NOT( ISBLANK(calls[tHandle])))
return

divide (_handle, _CallCount)
```

[image]